# Facebook API - delete status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

In PHP, I'm using curl to send a delete to the fb graph api - and yet I'm getting the following error;

```
{"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported delete request."}}
```

The code I'm using is;

```
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $status_id . ""); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;
```

$query contains the access token.

Comment: what's "status_id" ? a feed entry? is it valid?

Comment: the id of the status in question. and yes it's valid - have checked it with a get id pull which returns the status.

Comment: Have you solved your Problem? James Hartwig said he found a solution, but it is not marked as answer (and does not really work for me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed!

You have to prepend the userid to the object ID when deleting:

DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/673509687_104812882909249?access_token={access_token}
where
673509687 is my userID and 104812882909249 is the objectID

Comment: +1 for prepending the user id. -1 to Facebook for a crappy API.

Comment: I believe that user_id should be suffixed instead of prefixed to object_id.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this, I found out what my issue was attempting to delete application requests that I had previously created using the PHP SDK, which was resulting in this error.

(#2) Invalid parameter: Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid parameter

The problem was essentially with which access token was being used; user or application.

The specific scenario I was working on was where a user in my application has invited a friend Facebook (using an app request) but then wants to revoke that invite. In this case I want to delete the app request on Facebook that was previously created. However, at this point in time, the logged in user is not the recipient of the app request, but the sender.

Looking at the PHP SDK code, it automatically uses the user access token if it has one, over the application access token. In fact, there doesn't appear to be a way to explicitly  get the application token from the SDK.

When attempting to delete the app request using the following...

$facebook->api('/'.$fb_request_id, 'DELETE');

...and letting the PHP SDK choose the user token, I received the (#2) Invalid parameter error message. However, if I manually construct the application access token (where the format is "$app_id|$app_secret" and pass it as an array key in a third parameter...

$facebook->api('/'.$fb_request_id, 'DELETE', array('access_token' => $app_access_token);

..then the call succeeds.

So, essentially you need to use the application access token to delete the app requests if the current user is not the recipient of the app request.

I hope this helps anyone else struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code slightly. (Should echo "true" if done correctly) Here's what is currently working for me.

Also note this does not erase events created via Facebook.That's why your receiving the permissions error. This only erases events created through your application... (application linked to $app_id, $app_secret)

```
//First authenticate a token


$app_id = "APP ID GOES HERE";
$app_secret = "SECRET APP ID GOES HERE";
$my_url = "WHATEVER THIS PAGES NAME IS GOES HERE";  


//I'm not sure but I think REQUEST is still allowed....right? if not change it to GET/POST

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&scope=create_event";
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);




//Use TRUE and FALSE not 0 and 1's like you originally had it

//264853420218553 is the event id.

$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/264853420218553?" . $access_token . ""); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;?>
```

Comment: Please note a bug in the above code: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be an integer parameter, and should be set to 2 (the default). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more details. If you set the value to `true`, you're actually disabling host checking, and therefore enabling MITM attacks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think to try is to

1) do a POST request with "method=delete" to see if that works

2) manually look at the produced HTTP request to see if something looks wrong -- then you can isolate the problem

Comment: Hi Thr4wn. I've tried to do POST with the method=delete but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the HTTP delete method isn't supported for that specific object.

One option is to use Http POST and add method=delete to the parameter query. Make sure that your application has a `publish_stream` permission else you can never publish a feed.
Permissions are done by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

About this answer:

> Fixed!
>   You have to prepend the userid to the object ID when deleting:
>   DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/673509687_104812882909249?access_token={access_token} 
>   where 673509687 is my userID and 104812882909249 is the objectID

Unfortunately this will only work with a user-accesstoken and not when you try to delete an apprequest on the server (with the app-access-token) using for example the PHP language.

If you have a solution for deleting apprequests using the app-access-token then please describe it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you delete a user's status message with an app-access-token? I didn't think so...