# facebook graph api & php sdk, deleting events!

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For the life of me, I cannot find a way to delete, cancel or remove facebook events I created & updated using the FB PHP SDK & the Graph API.

I've tried every single permutation found on facebook's documentation & stack overflow...

Here are some of the clues I have found on my quest..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#deleting
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.cancel/

[Facebook SDK and Graph API Comment Deleting Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931387/facebook-sdk-and-graph-api-comment-deleting-error)

[Facebook API - delete status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858748/facebook-api-delete-status)

[Facebook Graph API - delete like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832405/facebook-graph-api-delete-like)

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
function delete_fb_event($event_data, $data)
{
    //load the user for offline access and userid
    $user = $this->load_user($data['aid']);

    if(!empty($user[0]['fb_offline_access']))
    {
        //instantiate Facebook API
        require 'facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'BLAHBLAHBLAH',
          'secret' => 'BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH',
          'cookie' => true,
        ));

        $fb_event = array(
            "access_token" => $user[0]['fb_offline_access'],
        );

        $result = $facebook->api('/'.$event_data['fb_event_id'], 'DELETE', $fb_event); //Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request
        //$result = $facebook->api('/'.$user[0]['fb_id']."_".$event_data['fb_event_id'], 'POST', array('access_token' => $user[0]['fb_offline_access'], 'method' => 'delete')); Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist
        //$result = $facebook->api('/'.$event_data['fb_event_id']."_".$user[0]['fb_id'], 'POST', array('access_token' => $user[0]['fb_offline_access'], 'method' => 'delete')); Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist  
        //$result = $facebook->api('/'.$event_data['fb_event_id'], 'POST', array('access_token' => $user[0]['fb_offline_access'], 'method' => 'delete')); Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported post request
        //$result = $facebook->api('/'.$user[0]['fb_id']."_".$event_data['fb_event_id'], 'POST', array( 'access_token' => $user[0]['fb_offline_access'], 'method' => 'delete' )); Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist
        return $result;         
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error3"; //no FB offline access
    }       
}
```

Comment: I'll start looking at it when I get home (assuming my electricity is turned back on) ^_^

Comment: Peter, I also had a go at this today using your examples (and a couple variations). Like Gublooo I too receive 200 Permission Error. Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope :( I did manage to get on their forums and was simply told the issue was resolved, yet no example or solution was provided... Some of their API stuff is CRAP...

Answer (score 3):

Hey Peter,
I tried running your code and I'm sorry to say I didn't have much success either.

My first guess was that you probably did not have the extended permissions - for deleting an event, you need to have to create_event permission

Although I tried with that, I keep getting the #200 Permission Error

On further digging I ran into a similar bug that was reported

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12777

Interestingly - although this bug has been marked as resolved - if you read the comments, users are still reporting the same issue.

Sorry wasn't able to offer much help.
Good luck