# How are Facebook events DELETED with php-sdk?

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-php-sdk

Has anyone figured out how to delete an event using the Facebook php-sdk?  Not finding documentation on how to do this.

Comment: You might be interested in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012268/facebook-graph-api-php-sdk-deleting-events

Comment: Have you asked for the `create_event` permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
$tokenArray = array(
    'access_token' => $token
);
$facebook->api('/'.$fbEventId, "DELETE", $tokenArray);
```