# Facebook apprequest deletes not working

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, api

I'm fairly new to the Facebook API, so I did some research and came across the Stack Overflow post *[Cannot delete application invite in Facebook after acceptance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287347/cannot-delete-application-invite-in-facebook-after-acceptance)*

I thought it would work for me since I have the same issue. However, I have not made any progress with any variations of the suggested methods in the post above.

These are the two variations I've been trying:

A:

=============================

```
FB.api('/'+request_id, 'DELETE', function(fb_response) {
    if (typeof callbackFunction == 'function') {
        callbackFunction(fb_response);
    }
});
```

B:

===================

```
FB.api("/", "POST", {
    access_token:"MY_APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    batch:[
        {
                "method":"DELETE",
                "name":request_id,
                //"omit_response_on_success": true,

        }
    ]
}, function(fb_response) {
    callbackFunction(fb_response);
});
```

I'm still getting this error message:

> message:"(#2) Invalid parameter: Unknown error"
>
> type:"OAuthException"

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You should really be doing that as a server side call, otherwise you'd need to have your app's access token available to the user's browser which is a massive security issue for your app - it's also easier to debug if it's server side.

Comment: well i've tried doing the graph api call manually through the browser to test it out as it would be done via PHP side through a curl call but i get the same error.


` https://graph.facebook.com/request_id?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=DELETE `

this is what i assume the call does through graph api.

Comment: Yeah, as per my answer on the other question you linked that should be working
Are you able to access the requests (i.e a `GET` request) OK? If not, there may be some other issue, because your app's access token should work for both

Comment: My gets are fine with the access token and such i just did it a few mins ago. it's the DELETE that hasn't been working griefing me for the past few weeks.

Comment: not sure if this helps or not but i ran the delete thing through the Graph API Explorer and it worked fine on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was my access_token. It was grabbing the user token instead of the app_token for some reason, and I decided, as suggested, to move the removable to the PHP side and all was dandy.

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways I am deleting requests through the js api:

Singular:

```
FB.api(request_id, 'DELETE', function(fb_response) {
    if (fb_response) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Batch:

```
FB.api("/", "POST", {
  batch:[
    {
            "method":"DELETE",
            "relative_url":request_id, 
    }
  ]
  }, function(fb_response) {
    if (fb_response){  
     // Do Something
    }
});
```

With the request_id being in the proper format of facebook request_id, underscore, facebook user_id.